# JavaScript UDF fails in Airflow but works in Bigquery

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, airflow

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION replace_all(input_string STRING, replace_list ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS 
r"""
myarray=input_string.split(" ")
for (var i = 0; i < replace_list.length; i++)
   {
      for(var j=0;j < myarray.length;j++){
        if(myarray[j]==replace_list[i]){
          myarray[j] =''
        }
      }
      
  }
  input_string =  myarray.join(' ')
  return input_string;
""";
```

This above function throws error **'Unclosed triple-quoted raw string literal'** when executed in Airflow. This is a function which I have defined in my query. Works good at bigquey console but errored out in Airflow.

Any inputs how the above error can be resolved.

Comment: can you share a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of you airflow dag script, please. If its python """ have a meaning there.

Comment: could it be that Airflow is using triple-quoted to encode the query? Then using `'''` instead of `"""` should help. I would recomend not use a temp function but to save the UDF in your project.

Comment: bq_extract_task_name = BigQuerySQLStatementOperator(
    task_id='bq_extract_task_name',
    sql="""N/A""",
    bq_sql_file_name=airflow_gcs + '/sql_scripts/' + 'sample.sql',
    create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    dml=True,
    destination_dataset_table='dataset_name',
    allow_large_results=True,
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    flatten_results=False,
    xcom_task_id='ilr_read',
    on_success_callback= data_tracking_write,
    on_failure_callback= data_tracking_write,
    dag=dag)

Comment: Using ' ' ' didn't resolve the issue still the same error is thrown. Above is the task which triggers the sql where the function is defined